# Open multiple windows popunder javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I'd like to open multiple different windows with the following script. For example, 1st google.com, 2nd yahoo.com, 3rd stackoverflow.com ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pup = 0;

function pop() {
    if (pup === 0) {
        win2 = window.open('http://google.com', 'pop', 'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,copyhistory=0,menuBar=0,width=1,height=1,');
        setTimeout("win2.close()", 2500)
        window.focus(); // supprimez ces 2 lignes si vous voulez un popup
        pop.blur(); // laissez les pour un popunder
        pup = 1;
    }
}
document.onclick = pop;
</script>
```

I've tried many things but nothing works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Alright, thanks for the information...   What is your actual question

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Popunders are the worst practice you can possibly inflict on your users...

Comment: I guess in reality, it will be `"russianwhores.com"`, `"giveusallyourmoney.com"` and `"leaveinfearandterror.com"`

Comment: So what it does? Does it make monkeys fall from the sky? gives you a pie?? what it does actually?

Comment: Your `setTimeout` will execute in the global scope. Try: `setTimeout(function () { win2.close(); }, 2500);` (sorry for encouraging this popunder stuff, but this was bothering me)

Comment: @sircapsalot the question is : What do I edit in the script ?